# Distribution of k-combinations

Tags: clojure, combinations, combinatorics

I am generating all possible subsets/3-combinations from a list in Clojure (disregarding the ordering of the combinations elements - i.e. subset ABC is the same as CBA etc.).

For the list (A B C D E F G) the result of my combinations is 35 in total as below:

```
("A" "B" "C")
("A" "B" "D")
("A" "B" "E")
("A" "B" "F")
("A" "B" "G")
("A" "C" "D")
("A" "C" "E")
("A" "C" "F")
("A" "C" "G")
("A" "D" "E")
("A" "D" "F")
("A" "D" "G")
("A" "E" "F")
("A" "E" "G")
("A" "F" "G")
("B" "C" "D")
("B" "C" "E")
("B" "C" "F")
("B" "C" "G")
("B" "D" "E")
("B" "D" "F")
("B" "D" "G")
("B" "E" "F")
("B" "E" "G")
("B" "F" "G")
("C" "D" "E")
("C" "D" "F")
("C" "D" "G")
("C" "E" "F")
("C" "E" "G")
("C" "F" "G")
("D" "E" "F")
("D" "E" "G")
("D" "F" "G")
("E" "F" "G")
```

This is all good except I need to have the combination pairs distributed "evenly", i.e. a combination pair containing "A" should only be repeated when all other items in the list has been used in a combination, e.g. as below:

```
("A" "B" "C")
("D" "E" "F")
("A" "B" "G")
("C" "D" "E")
("A" "F" "G")
... and onwards
```

I surely expect this to be a general problem which has been solved a lot of times before, but I am having a hard time figuring out the direction of my further research into the issue. Any suggestions on algorithms to look into or base further research on?

I generate the combinations like below.

```clj
(defn k-combinations [n items]
  (concat (map
            #(cons (first items) %)                         
            (subsets (dec n) (rest items)))
          (subsets n (rest items))))

(defn subsets [n items]
  (cond
    (= n 0) '(())                                           
    (empty? items) '()                                      
    :else (k-combinations n items)))

(subsets 3 '("A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G"))
```

Comment: Is the rule that no consecutive lines can have any elements in common? If so, are you sure it's always possible?

Comment: Yes, that is the rule which is my starting ground. But no, I am not sure its always possible - good point! However, as long as I can distribute the combinations close to "evenly" I will be much happier than with the current subset generation.

Comment: Did you check this library? https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics